# HTML: content height exclude footer

Tags: html, css

Here is my code: 
css

```
*{
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
#table {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#table_cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
}
.glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 11px 10px 10px 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#username,
#password,
#mail {
  position: relative
}
#username-input,
#password-input {
  padding-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block!important;
  width: 270px!important;
  height: 37px!important;
}
footer {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 0 0 -15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e7eaec;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

html

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="table">
      <div id="table_cell">
        <form name="login_form" id="login_form" method="post" action="">
          <img src="images/this.png" />
          <br/>
          <div id="username">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
            <input autofocus type="text" class="form-control" name="base_u_username" id="username-input" placeholder="Username" />
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div id="password">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
            <input autocomplete="off" type="password" class="form-control" name="base_u_password" id="password-input" placeholder="Password" />
          </div>
          <br/>

          <span style="float:right;">
              <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-default" value="Login" />
            </span> 
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      footer
      <br>footer

    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am struggling with my page layout.
I know there are some similar posts, I try but looks like my case is different.
How can my `<div id=table>` height exclude footer?
If possible, I don't wish to set a number for height.
Thanks.

Comment: actually code included.

Comment: What does meaning of "*height exclude footer*" ?

Comment: if you inspect element, you can see my <div id=table> height is overlay on my footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `position: absolute;` from `footer`.

**Edit:**

One better solution is remove height and minheight from `body`, `#table` and `.container` and use `display:flex`.

Give following css to `.container`

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
min-height: 100vh;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
}
html {
}
body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
#table {
  display: table;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
#table_cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
}
.glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 11px 10px 10px 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#username,
#password,
#mail {
  position: relative
}
#username-input,
#password-input {
  padding-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block!important;
  width: 270px!important;
  height: 37px!important;
}
footer {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 0 -15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e7eaec;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="table">
      <div id="table_cell">
        <form name="login_form" id="login_form" method="post" action="">
          <img src="images/this.png" />
          <br/>
          <div id="username">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
            <input autofocus type="text" class="form-control" name="base_u_username" id="username-input" placeholder="Username" />
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div id="password">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
            <input autocomplete="off" type="password" class="form-control" name="base_u_password" id="password-input" placeholder="Password" />
          </div>
          <br/>

          <span style="float:right;">
        <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-default" value="Login" />
      </span> 
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      footer
      <br>footer

    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but then my footer overflow of my page.

Comment: @YingRuiWong i can see footer properly in the page

Comment: I mean there will be a scroll bar for whole page if remove the position:absolute, cos i dont want to let my page to scroll

Answer (score 0):

add this css

```
#table {
    display: table;
    height: calc(100% - 31px);
}
```

Change css for footer

```
footer {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #e7eaec;
    bottom: 0;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```